# Select points by continuous numbers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I have GPS points driven over the same road back and forth then clipped to a section of that road. My points are overlapping and need to identify the points going one way or one run down the road in order to make a new feature from it. My points have consecutive numbers but stop being consecutive where the point file was clipped. I'm thinking this would be the best way find the run segment points in one direction.

I have tried using the "Group Analysis" tool, which has got me very close but it is failing to find all the breakpoints in the consecutive number string

An example is one run going north: points 989,990,991 then the next run going South on the same road, points 1088,1089,1090. Where the North run will make a new feature and the South run a new feature. We can do this manually but have over 100 runs and would like to automate it.

[image: break points needed to be defined]

Comment: What is your question?  Are you asking how to *select* features with consecutive numbers, or how to *calculate* a value onto a field where another field has consecutive numbers?  You have tagged both Select by Attribute and Field Calculator, so I'm unsure which you are wanting help with.  Please **[edit]** your question to clarify the problem that you're stuck with.  Include any select statements or field calculator code that you've tried.

Comment: I am trying to select features with consecutive numbers to create a new feature, not create or calculate consecutive numbers into a field. The closest I have got is using the Grouping Analysis tool but it failed to find some of the numerical break points

Comment: Please use the **[edit]** link below your question to add more info including showing what you've actually tried in the Select by Attributes.